# Initial blockchain sync fails with message: [P2P6]Attempt to get hash from height 787402 failed -- hash not in db

Tags: monerod, synchronization

I've attempted to get monerod running on one of my Linux boxes, and keep getting an error during the initial synchronization.
I've deleted the .bitmonero directory as well as the working directory, but get the same result. I was hoping the latest version released today might fix it, but the issue persists.

SYNCHRONIZATION started

2016-Dec-22 11:35:21.224232 [P2P6]Attempt to get hash from height 787402 failed -- hash not in db

2016-Dec-22 11:35:21.224284 [P2P6]ERROR /DISTRIBUTION-BUILD/contrib/epee/include/net/abstract_tcp_server2.inl:249 Exception at [connection::call_back_starter()], what=Attempt to get hash from height 787402 failed -- hash not in db

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a Monero problem (see andwer). Voting for deletion if possible.

Comment: Question was legit. The answer should be marked as accepted and that's it.

Answer (score 3):

The issue ended up being a bad stick of RAM.  I removed the memory and the problem went away.